# RecyclerView items changes randomly on clicking an item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I have a RecyclerView list, I want the color of the clicked item to be changed. But whenever I am clicking an item the RecyclerView items change randomly.

I have also taken a boolean in my data class to keep track of item selection.

data class

```
data class OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem(
val actual_date: String,
val day_name: String,
val date_name: String,
val day_num: Int,

// For item selection
var isDateSelected: Boolean)
```

Inside my fragment, checking if the clicked item matches the list item and updating the isDateSelected to true, then calling notifydatasetchanged.

```
private var availableDaysList: OrderAvailableDaysResponse = OrderAvailableDaysResponse()
orderAvailableDaysAdapter.setDateClickListener {
        for(resItem in availableDaysList){
            resItem.isDateSelected = resItem.date_name == it.date_name
        }
        orderAvailableDaysAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Adapter clicklistener

```
var onDateClickListener: ((OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem) -> Unit)? = null
fun setDateClickListener(listener: (OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem) -> Unit){
    onDateClickListener = listener
}

inner class AvailableDaysViewHolder(binding: ItemAvailableDaysBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun setBindings(itemRes: OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem){
        binding.resItem = itemRes
        binding.executePendingBindings()

        binding.clRoot.setOnClickListener {
            onDateClickListener?.let {
                it(itemRes)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please refer to the attachment for a better understanding of the situation

[image]

As you can see on clicking on an item the items are changing randomly. Please help me. Am I missing something?

Edit 1:

Complete adapter code

```
class OrderAvailableDaysAdapter(var orderAvailableDaysResponseList: OrderAvailableDaysResponse) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAvailableDaysAdapter.AvailableDaysViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var binding: ItemAvailableDaysBinding

var onDateClickListener: ((OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem) -> Unit)? = null
fun setDateClickListener(listener: (OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem) -> Unit){
    onDateClickListener = listener
}

inner class AvailableDaysViewHolder(binding: ItemAvailableDaysBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun setBindings(itemRes: OrderAvailableDaysResponseItem){
        binding.resItem = itemRes
        binding.executePendingBindings()

        binding.clRoot.setOnClickListener {
            onDateClickListener?.let {
                it(itemRes)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AvailableDaysViewHolder {
    binding = ItemAvailableDaysBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return AvailableDaysViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AvailableDaysViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.setBindings(orderAvailableDaysResponseList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return orderAvailableDaysResponseList.size
}}
```

Comment: show adapters code

Comment: Please check, I have added adapter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `private lateinit var binding: ItemAvailableDaysBinding` from adapter, don' keep it "globally", initialisation is made only once, in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AvailableDaysViewHolder {
    ItemAvailableDaysBinding binding = ItemAvailableDaysBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return AvailableDaysViewHolder(binding)
}
```

same naming of this "global" object and in `AvailableDaysViewHolder` inner class may confuse it and `setBindings` may be called on lastly initialised (global kept) object rather that this passed in constructor

Comment: OMG you saved my day. "don' keep it "globally", initialisation is made only once, in onCreateViewHolder" . This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.